# SensioLabs Security Check Error Symfony 5

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony5

I installed the SensioLabs security checker recipe using composer and it looks like it installed the recipe but I get the following two warnings

### symfony/http-foundation (v5.0.5)

- [CVE-2020-5255][]: Prevent cache poisoning via a Response Content-Type header

### symfony/security-http (v5.0.5)

- [CVE-2020-5275][]: All rules set in "access_control" are required when the firewall is configured with the unanimous strategy

I would like to know what I should do to fix this please? I am using the latest version of Symfony 5 on a Linux Mint 19 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the security checker is to inform you about packages you have in your `composer.lock` with security issues - for example, `symfony/http-foundation` has an issue listed at https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-5255.

To resolve these warnings, you should update the packages - either update all packages using `composer update` or do this selectively by adding the name of the package (like `composer update symfony/http-foundation`)

Comment: I did what you said and it updated everything, but it removed the security checker. Is there a reason it removed it and so can I not use that feature anymore? I thought it a nice feature to be able to check security. - Removing sensiolabs/security-checker (v6.0.3)

Comment: Sorry where do I find the logs I am on a Linux Mint machine?

Comment: After I updated I just installed it again and everything works now

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has released some security fixes. Current version is now 5.0.7 you must upgrade your symfony version to fix this message.